# How to set up custom routes with 3 NICs

Tags: networking, proxy

This is my network topology:

[image]

I want every data proxy incoming request to `eth0` to reply via `eth0` , as well `eth1` will reply to the data coming into `eth1` too...

Active Route :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.110.1   0.0.0.0         UG    15     0        0 eth2
192.168.110.96  *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.200.0   *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.200.96  *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I tried with these commands but it's not working... :(

```
ip route flush table 2002
ip route flush table 2001

ip route add 10.10.8.0/22     dev eth0 src 192.168.200.2   table 2002
ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.200.2   table 2002
ip route add default via 192.168.200.1 table 2002

ip route add 10.10.8.0/22     dev eth1 src 192.168.200.101 table 2001
ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.200.101 table 2001
ip route add default via 192.168.200.100 table 2001

ip rule add from 192.168.200.2   table 2002
ip rule add from 192.168.200.101 table 2001
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.  Eth0 is probably for the LAN clients and connected to a switch and then to the internal router.  Eth2 is probably connected to an external router, but what is Eth1 connected to?

Comment: All Eth..is connected to 1 router... Eth1 is a local web+ftp server which serves to my local client for download big files (Films etc..). I dont want to impose it all in one eth. i want request proxy data from eth0 will reply in eth0...and request local download come in eth1 will reply in eth1....(sorry if my english is bad)

Comment: Your English is good enough!  ;-)  I don't understand your set-up!  Are they all connected to the same router???

Comment: here my network topology (http://i61.tinypic.com/2j1saj8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Now I know why I didn't understand...  Routing is done on a network level and not on a port level.  You need to sub-segment your network in 3 separate networks and bind each network to each network card and then have your router route the packets to the correct Ethernet port.

As each network card has its own network address, any packets coming in with a certain address will also go back out on that network.

E.g.:

- eth0: 192.168.100.0/24 LAN
- eth1: 192.168.101.0/24 Access Point
- Eth3: Default gateway/24: ADSL modem

Then all traffic that is not for 192.168.0.0/16 will go out to the Internet and all local traffic will stay local.

To do port forwarding you have two options:

1. If you add an additional piece of hardware [like a Big-IP](https://f5.com/products/big-ip) between the router and the server, that will be able to inspect the packets and depending on ports send stuff to Eth0 and Eth1 by changing the IP address on-the-fly and then the server will then again send it out on the correct interface, and the BigIP will then convert it back to whatever it was...
2. You can also drop the router entirely and *use the server as a router* to accomplish the same thing, and then you just use `iptables` to inspect the packets and route them around.

But what you're trying to do is impossible (only using a hardware router and software routing in the server) as there is no notion of "HTTP/FTP" as that is on a port level...  **:-(**

Comment: thank's for ur answer, I really appreciate it.... but in my case server dont need To do port forwarding..port forwarding just be done from the router side (CMIIW ) ... i have reference like my case.... (http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) but i confused implement into my case

Comment: So is the router a piece of hardware or an Ubuntu box?

Comment: No... i'am using mikrotik router...
and I have tested the data transmission performed by the router are correct..this pict can proof it http://oi60.tinypic.com/260tu7s.jpg

Comment: Now you don't understand me!  **;-** Routing is IP based.  What you want to do is port-based...  You need different technology!  **And as the [Mikrotik](http://www.mikrotik.com/software) router does not run Ubuntu, this question is not about Ubuntu any more and off-topic here.**

Comment: i'am just explain routing port based from mikrotik is not have problem... and ubuntu as machine with 3 NIC have problem to reply data by ip based...which NIC receives data will reply via other NIC....and that problem can be solved by custom route..

Comment: and why ubuntu always reply via 1 NIC...in my route i added command :

    route add -net 192.168.100.0/24 via 192.168.200.1 dev eth0

and i know i cant add one dest with 2 gateway like this :

    route add -net 192.168.100.0/24 via 192.168.110.101 dev eth0
    route add -net 192.168.100.0/24 via 192.168.200.1   dev eth1

i need route command which distinguish incomming data from NIC...
in my refference site, that can be done by ubuntu with custom route CMIIW